# Picture not showing up on my webpage

Tags: html, image

I have a very simple webpage with four pictures that are places using . All are .jpg format. The first three are pictures that are my own, created from Lightroom. They don't show up as broken links on the site. 
The fourth one is a picture that I just downloaded from the internet and uploaded it to my site using the exact same code as the other three and it shows up. 
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your code your first. May be there some spelling mistake. Also check image path and image name as per real name.